# Html form on submit ? and &

Tags: html, forms

I have got a search input field.

It redirects you after submit to `search.php?keyword=(value from input)`

I would like to get it like this

```
search.php?keyword=(value from input)&cd=(its the current directory I got a method to get this)
```

i just don't know how to get a `&cd=` in the url

**Code**

```
<form name="myform" action="search.php" method="GET">
<div class="filter-field">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="twelve columns">
      <div class="row collapse">
       <div class="nine mobile-three columns">
        <input type="text" name="keyword">
       </div>
       <div class="three mobile-one columns">

        <span class="postfix" onclick="myform.submit()"></span>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Add an hidden input field called "cd" and with the proper value into your form.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean by current directory, the directory or file path where the file is, try this as an additional input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cd" value="<?PHP echo getcwd(); ?>" />
```